# How to automate the calculation of the average entry price for every new entry price and contract size added in an Excel sheet? trading related

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, trading

## Context

- ***Entry Price*** (*a.k.a. [Entry Point](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/entry-point.asp#:%7E:text=An%20entry%20point%20refers%20to,order%20for%20a%20short%20position.)*) *refers to the price at which an investor initiates a position in a security.  A trade entry can be initiated with either a buy order for a long position, or sell order for a short position.*
- ***Average Entry Price*** *refers to the central price at which an investor is positioned in a security in order to increase potential profits and exit the market more easily, it can take different entry prices as well as different quantity of contracts (a.k.a. [contract size](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/contractsize.asp#:%7E:text=our%20editorial%20policies-,What%20Is%20Contract%20Size%3F,the%20terms%20of%20the%20contract.))*

### Manual calculation of the Average Entry Price in an Excel Sheet

Based on [this article](https://www.bybit.com/fr-FR/help-center/bybitHC_Article?language=fr&id=000001113), I managed to calculate the Average Entry Price as follows:

- Say you have the following **Entry Prices:**
  `[16500,16400,16300,16200]`
- And also you have the following **Quantity of Contracts** pegged to those **Entry Prices** respectively:
  `[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]`

Such information will be stored in a table like this one:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 |  |
| 16400 | 0,1 |  |
| 16300 | 0,1 |  |
| 16200 | 0,1 |  |

Now, the correspondingly average entry price formulas were written as follows (assume the position name of the columns is A,B,C respectively):

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | `=B3/(B3/A3)` |
| 16400 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4)/(B3+B4)` |
| 16300 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4+A5 * B5)/(B3+B4+B5)` |
| 16200 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4+A5 * B5+ A6*B6)/(B3+B4+B5+B6)` |

Finally, the results were the following:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | 16500 |
| 16400 | 0,1 | 16450 |
| 16300 | 0,1 | 16400 |
| 16200 | 0,1 | 16350 |

## Problem

How could I automate the calculation of the **Average Entry Price** for every new value of **Entry Prices** and **Quantity** pasted in the last row of the table? The expected output would be something like this:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | 16500 |
| 16400 | 0,1 | 16450 |
| 16300 | 0,1 | 16400 |
| 16200 | 0,1 | 16350 |
| 16100 | 0,1 | 16300 |
| 16000 | 0,1 | 16250 |
| 15900 | 0,1 | 16200 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are indeed working with a table as per your description:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX([Entry Price],1):[@[Entry Price]],INDEX([Quantity (BTC)],1):[@[Quantity (BTC)]])/SUM(INDEX([Quantity (BTC)],1):[@[Quantity (BTC)]])
```

This will now autopopulate upon new entries:

[image]

Comment: Hmph, I see, but I'm getting an error that says `There's a problem with that formula`, I tried changing th e name of the functions to my native language but I still keep getting the same error. I also noticed that the name of the columns in the formula don't get colored, just the very first one.

Comment: Do you need semicolon instead of comma @NoahVerner?

Comment: OMG You are right, that was exactly what needed to be changed. I used the following statement: `=SUMAPRODUCTO(INDICE([Entry Price];1):[@[Entry Price]];INDICE([Quantity (BTC)];1):[@[Quantity (BTC)]])/SUMA(INDICE([Quantity (BTC)];1):[@[Quantity (BTC)]])`